# How do I map keys for specific file types in Vim?

Tags: vim

I want my <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to follow links in help files because my keyboard doesn't have a <kbd>]</kbd> key. Therefore I've put:

```
nnoremap <Enter> <C-]>
```

In `ftplugin/help.vim`. This works, but this key map is now "global" and messes up the use of the key in other places, for example the `q:` command window.

So how do I restrict a key-bind to a single buffer, or perhaps even a single file type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `<buffer>` to your mapping:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <Enter> <C-]>
```

Answer (score 16):

map the command using [autocmd](http://www.shawnbiddle.com/snippets/mapped-commenting):

```
autocmd FileType c,cpp,php nnoremap <buffer> <Enter> <C-]>
```

maps only for filetypes: c,cpp and php

Comment: Sure it will only perform the remap when editing a specific file type, but won't the mapping be active in all buffers after that? Is this example in effect any different than mine?

Comment: @Codemonkey, the final step is making the mapping local to the buffer as follows: `autocmd FileType c,cpp,php nnoremap <buffer> <Enter> <C-]>`

Comment: @mtth: That should probably be included in the answer then

Comment: @mtth: Also that appears to work without all the autocmd noise. You should put that in a new answer.