# How do I map space key for specific filetypes in nvim in insert mode?

Tags: neovim

I want to map double space ("  ") to output ". " in insert mode, but only for md, tex and txt filetypes. I tried pretty much everything, making md.vim file in ftplugin directory, making an autocmd, but neither works.

The last autocmd I tried was

`autocmd FileType md inoremap <buffer> <space><space> .<space>`

It does not work. What do I do?

Tried pretty much everything I could think of using autocmd, just like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105440/how-do-i-map-keys-for-specific-file-types-in-vim?newreg=4153b9ed2cd045d4a7460123724a7795) issue.

Is there any solution? Preferably using lua, like vim.keymap.set() function

Comment: try changing _md_ to _markdown_ I think this is correct filetype value for markdown files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had to set *markdown* as a filetype, your *vimscript* was correct, here is an example of how to do it in *lua*:

```lua
local group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("markdown_autocommands", { clear = true })
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("FileType", {
    pattern = {"markdown", "txt"}, -- here you can add additional filetypes
    callback = function(ev)
        -- actual mapping
        vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(0, 'i', '<space><space>', '.<space>', { noremap = true, silent = true })
    end,
    group = group 
})
```

- Checkout neovim help for nvim_create_augroup_, and *nvim_create_autocmd*
- Regarding clearance of autocommand [groups](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html) and why bother creating groups at all.
- I don't use *tex* files, so I don't know what name of this filetype in neovim, you can open a *tex* file and check its file type with `:set filetype?` command.